# Chinese characters in Intellij IDEA - how to show?

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding, intellij-idea, cjk

I have UTF-8 encoded XML file, which has Chinese characters. Questions are:

1. Should I translate Chinese characters to entities like `&#160;`
   or XML parser will work smooth with Chinese ones?
2. How to push Intellij IDEA so it will show actual Chinese hieroglyphs instead of showing empty quadrats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, you don't need to encode them if the encoding is specified correctly in the XML prolog.
2. Most likely the font that you are using in the IDE doesn't have the required glyphs, so it displays square boxes. To fix this problem go to `Settings` | `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts` and change the editor font to the one that has Chinese glyphs in it.

Answer (score 2):

The XML parser should be fine with the characters, if they really *have* been encoded properly.

I don't use Intellij myself, but I would try:

- Check the font used - make sure you're using one which supports the characters you need
- Check that the editor understands it's a UTF-8 file. I'd expect it to pick up the encoding from the XML, but if there are manual ways of setting the encoding, that's worth a try as well.

Comment: Thanx for explanations with parser... Your other suggestion - I have to check