# Chinese characters are not displayed correctly when running quarkus directly in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, quarkus

Chinese characters are not displayed correctly when running quarkus directly in IDEA.

- IDEA version : IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 (Ultimate Edition)
- Quarkus version : 2.5.4.Final
- Quarkus Tools for IntelliJ version : 1.9.0.185
- JDK version : graalvm-jdk17
- maven version : 3.8.4

```xml
<maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>

<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
```

When I start quarkus directly with idea's run function, no matter what my **file.encoding** parameter is set to **UTF-8** or **GBK**, it does not display Chinese characters correctly, as shown in the following image :

UTF-8 :
[image]
[image]

GBK :
[image]
[image]

But hen I run **quarkus:dev** in the **terminal**, the Chinese characters are displayed correctly, as shown in the picture :

[image]
[image]

I don't know the cause of this problem is the IDEA or the quarkus tool or the quarkus framework.

I tried to attach more information :

```java
System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));//GBK
System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());//GBK
```

```java
System.out.println("注意身体,适度看漫");//Right
//注意身体,适度看漫
```

```java
logger.info(new String("注意身体,适度看漫".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));//Right
//2021-12-30 19:53:49,920 INFO  [io.git.jia.fin.run.ComicRunner] (Quarkus Main Thread) 注意身体,适度看漫
```

```java
logger.info("注意身体,适度看漫");//Error
//2021-12-30 19:53:49,920 INFO  [io.git.jia.fin.run.ComicRunner] (Quarkus Main Thread) ???????,??????
```

```java
logger.info(new String("注意身体,适度看漫".getBytes("GBK")));//Error
//2021-12-30 19:53:49,920 INFO  [io.git.jia.fin.run.ComicRunner] (Quarkus Main Thread) ???????,??????
```

Comment: did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/7345865/175554 ?

Comment: @özkanpakdil I tried, The problem still exists : (

Comment: can you show what did you set for font in intellij ? like in https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/quarkus-examples/issues/2 , you should choose "change the editor font to the one that has Chinese glyphs in it"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try:

Step1. use "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS" **key** and set "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" **value** in environment variables.

[image]

Step2. make sure your file encoding already set "UTF-8", from **Settings** | **Editor** | **File Encodings**

[image]

hope this can help you :)

Comment: I can't believe that I just added JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS= -dfile.encoding =UTF-8 to display Chinese correctly